# Radio Tray will not install or open

Tags: 14.04, dependencies

I'm affected with exactly this problem; mentions 14.04 
https://bitbucket.org/carlmig/radio-tray/issues/218/dependency-is-not-satisfiable-python. 
Not sure where to turn next. 
Purged reinstalled several times.

I had it installed for one day working, barely; failed and tried several purge reinstalls but now stuck/stopped. by the missing dependency. 
I have used it for several years and it works very well.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/263378/how-to-fix-dependencies-broken-packages    Have you tried aptitude? It has a resolver that might be helpful to you.

Comment: Further research indicates this is a bug in process of being squashed. See: https://bitbucket.org/carlmig/radio-tray/pull-requests/10/fix-up-debian-packaging-to-use-dh-python/diff

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139970/how-to-install-a-downloaded-deb-file

Comment: radiotray from ubuntu repos does not dep on  python-central, so what package are you trying to install?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'm assuming you are trying to install an older version that requires that package. To install that dependency, run the following commands:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-central/python-central_0.6.17ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-central_0.6.17ubuntu2_all.deb
```

Now, you should be able to install without the dependency issue.

[source](https://bitbucket.org/carlmig/radio-tray/issues/218/dependency-is-not-satisfiable-python)

---

Okay, since that didn't work, lets try the current version to see if that fixes the issue.

**WARNING:**

**The following steps will delete your current radiotray configuration and possibly any files associated with the application. You should make a backup of these file before you proceed!!!**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get purge radiotray
sudo apt-get install radiotray=0.7.3-1ubuntu1
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on that bug report, you should be able to run the following to fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly python-gst0.10 python-gtk2 python-lxml python-setuptools dh-python
```

Comment: First step yielded;

Comment: Still no go. please excuse the messed up replies.

Comment: @user73028 I have updated the instructions

Comment: Yield too long to post but result same.

Comment: @user73028 You can edit your question and post it there. Doing so may also help you get an answer from somebody that is familiar with the particular error.

Comment: thanks for your help mchid;      as eldergeek pointed out it's a bug in process of being squashed so I'll just sit tight

Comment: @user73028 okay, I looked at the bug report and provided some additional instructions to get the issue resolved. Please post any more errors.

Comment: 16.04 on two machines: one fresh install and the other do upgrade.  Radiotray working well on  both