# VirtualBox not working when installing

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

i get this error msg when doing `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox:
 virtualbox depends on virtualbox-dkms (>= 5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) | virtualbox-source (>= 5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) | virtualbox-modules; however:
  Package virtualbox-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-source is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-modules is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-dkms which provides virtualbox-modules is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
 virtualbox
 virtualbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: please [edit] your question and add: which version of Ubuntu are you using? which command did you execute which resulted with the errors provided in the question?

Comment: Even if you get it working you'll be on quite an old version.  Better to download the latest .deb file and install it with sudo dpkg -i filename.deb

Comment: Have you tried updating the cache, then opting to fix dependencies? The command is: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f` ; note there are no further options fter the `install -f` at this stage. Also, likely a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/263378/how-to-fix-dependencies-broken-packages

Comment: Nothing works. I tried everything. VirtualBox has never worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox*`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved mine in the past.

1. visit https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
2. Download the one that is applicable to your system.
3. Run from bash: `$ sudo dpkg -i filename.deb` to install it.

Comment: `error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-5.1_5.1.18-114002~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb`

Comment: sudo apt --fix-broken install.
solved me the peer dependencies problem.

Answer (score 0):

when additional dependencies are not getting installed,
it causes a broken install.

Install the broken dependencies manually using,

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

and trying again solved the issue.