# Unable to install Virtualbox 5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, virtualbox, dependencies

I am unable to install **Virtualbox5.1** from oracle ppa; with the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-5.1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.6.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.6.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but 5.5.1-3build1 is to be installed
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f`.

Comment: Seems like its been answered here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/898054/virtualbox-not-working-when-installing/898058#898058

Comment: @Pilot6 I do not want to force the update

Comment: @saviour123 the question pointed is regarding the default virtualbox i.e. 5.0 whereas I am facing problems with oracle PPA providing 5.1

Comment: `-f` is not "force", it is "fix". It should install the needed dependencies.

Comment: fixed the cache with `sudo apt install -f` still the same error persists, interestingly ubuntu based virtualbox 5.0 installs perfectly fine

Comment: I am using VB 5.1 with no problems. I installed a deb file and the PPA has been added automatically.

Comment: You might try upgrading from 16.04 to 16.04.02, or 16.10, and then retrying the Virtualbox 5.1 install. libsdl-ttf2.0-0 should probably come with the newer OS's.

Answer (score 0):

These are all dependencies for most recent VirtualBox 5.1.18 installed from the [Oracle repository](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) for Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS:

```
Dependencies:
5.1.18-114002~Ubuntu~xenial - debconf (18 1.1) debconf-2.0 (0 (null)) libc6 (2 2.15) libcurl3 (2 7.16.2) libdevmapper1.02.1 (2 2:1.02.97) libgcc1 (2 1:3.0) libgl1-mesa-glx (16 (null)) libgl1 (0 (null)) libpng12-0 (2 1.2.13-4) libpython2.7 (2 2.7) libqt5core5a (2 5.5.0) libqt5gui5 (18 5.3.0) libqt5gui5-gles (2 5.3.0) libqt5opengl5 (18 5.0.2) libqt5opengl5-gles (2 5.0.2) libqt5printsupport5 (2 5.0.2) libqt5widgets5 (2 5.2.0) libqt5x11extras5 (2 5.1.0) libsdl1.2debian (2 1.2.11) libssl1.0.0 (2 1.0.0) libstdc++6 (2 5.2) libvpx3 (2 1.5.0) libx11-6 (0 (null)) libxcb1 (0 (null)) libxcursor1 (4 1.1.2) libxext6 (0 (null)) libxinerama1 (0 (null)) libxml2 (2 2.7.4) libxmu6 (0 (null)) libxt6 (0 (null)) zlib1g (2 1:1.1.4) psmisc (0 (null)) adduser (0 (null)) virtualbox (0 (null)) virtualbox:i386 (0 (null)) virtualbox-guest-additions-iso (0 (null)) virtualbox-guest-additions-iso:i386 (0 (null)) virtualbox-ose (0 (null)) libasound2 (0 (null)) libpulse0 (0 (null)) libsdl-ttf2.0-0 (0 (null)) kmod (16 (null)) kldutils (16 (null)) module-init-tools (0 (null)) linux-headers-generic (16 (null)) linux-headers-generic-pae (16 (null)) linux-headers-686-pae (16 (null)) linux-headers-amd64 (16 (null)) linux-headers-2.6-686 (16 (null)) linux-headers-2.6-amd64 (16 (null)) linux-headers (0 (null)) linux-image (0 (null)) gcc (0 (null)) make (16 (null)) build-essential (16 (null)) dpkg-dev (0 (null)) binutils (0 (null)) pdf-viewer (0 (null)) libgl1 (0 (null)) virtualbox (0 (null)) virtualbox:i386 (0 (null)) virtualbox-5.1:i386 (32 (null)) 
Provides: 
5.1.18-114002~Ubuntu~xenial - virtualbox (= )
```

From that we can see that all dependent packages are available through the default installation. No need to install any future package release.

You may have accidentally downloaded or installed a Virtual Box version built for Ubuntu 16.10 or another distribution. Please [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack) on how to add the Oracle repository to your sources and make sure you use the appropriate Ubuntu release for the sources line:

```
lsb_release -sc
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**1.** `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.0_6.0.4-128413_Ubuntu_xenial_amd64.deb`

**2.** then it shows `Package libvpx3 is not installed.`.

**3.** `sudo apt-get update`.

**4.** `sudo apt-get install libvpx3`.