# Unmet dependencies when installing Wine

Tags: 14.04, apt, wine, dependencies

I'm trying to install Wine in Ubuntu 14.04, but I have some unmet dependencies and I have no idea how to fix them. I tried to install them manually, but things got worse and worse.

Results of running `sudo apt-get install wine`:

```
Reading package list....Done
Building Dependency tree
Reading state information...Done 
You may want to run 'apt-get -f install' to fix:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatk1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Breaks: libclutter-1.0-0:i386 (!= 1.16.4-0ubuntu2) but 1.10.0-0ubuntu1 it is going to be installed
 libclutter-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libcairo-gobject2:i386 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libcairo2:i386 (>= 1.10) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libcogl-pango0:i386 (>= 1.7.4) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libcogl9:i386 (>= 1.9.8) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgtk-3-0:i386 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386 (>= 0.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libpango1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.29.4) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libx11-6:i386 (>= 2:1.2.99.901) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libxcomposite1:i386 (>= 1:0.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libxdamage1:i386 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libxi6:i386 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but it is not going to be installed
                         Breaks: libclutter-1.0-0 (!= 1.10.0-0ubuntu1) but 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 it is going to be installed
 libcogl15 : Breaks: libclutter-1.0-0:i386 (= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libffi6:i386 (>= 3.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libpcre3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libselinux1:i386 (>= 1.32) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.40.2-0ubuntu1) but 2.40.0-2 is going to be installed
 wine : Depends: wine1.6
E: Unmet dependencies. Run 'apt-get -f install' without packages (or specify a solution).
```

I already tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Output:

```
nelson@nelson-hp:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package list....Done
Building Dependency tree
Reading state information...Done 
Correcting Dependencies.... failure
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatk1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2) but it is not installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Breaks: libclutter-1.0-0:i386 (!= 1.16.4-0ubuntu2) but 1.10.0-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libclutter-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libcairo-gobject2:i386 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libcairo2:i386 (>= 1.10) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libcogl-pango0:i386 (>= 1.7.4) pero no es instalable
                         Depends: libcogl9:i386 (>= 1.9.8) pero no es instalable
                         Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libgtk-3-0:i386 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386 (>= 0.12.0) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libpango1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.29.4) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libx11-6:i386 (>= 2:1.2.99.901) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libxcomposite1:i386 (>= 1:0.3-1) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libxdamage1:i386 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libxi6:i386 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but it is not installed
                         Breaks: libclutter-1.0-0 (!= 1.10.0-0ubuntu1) pero 1.16.4-0ubuntu2 está instalado
 libcogl15 : Breaks: libclutter-1.0-0:i386 (< 1.15) but 1.10.0-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libglib2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installed
                     Depends: libffi6:i386 (>= 3.0.4) but it is not installed
                     Depends: libpcre3:i386 but it is not installed
                     Depends: libselinux1:i386 (>= 1.32) but it is not installed
                     Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.2.2) but it is not installed
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.40.2-0ubuntu1) but 2.40.0-2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Unable to correct problems, this may have been caused by held packages.
E: Can't resolve the dependencies
```

I ran:

```
~$ sudo apt-cache policy libclutter-1.0-0:i386
```

Output:

```
libclutter-1.0-0:i386:
  Instalados: 1.10.0-0ubuntu1
  Candidato:  1.16.4-0ubuntu2
  Tabla de versión:
     1.16.4-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
 *** 1.10.0-0ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: `apt-get update && apt-get install -f` ; es duplicacion de http://askubuntu.com/questions/263378/how-to-fix-dependencies-broken-packages

Comment: I already tested those commands. I will edit the question to mention that.

Comment: It looks like your version of `libclutter` is from 12.04... Pleqse provide the output of `apt-cache policy libclutter-1.0-0`.

Comment: @fkraiem I edited the question with the output. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `libclutter-1.0-0:i386`.

Comment: @fkraiem updated!

Comment: This system was upgraded from 12.04, right? For some unknown reason, `libclutter-1.0-0:i386` was not upgraded to the 16.04 version, so let's try to do it manually: `sudo apt install libclutter-1.0-0:i386=1.16.4-0ubuntu2`.

Comment: Wait. this question is tagged 16.04, but you have 14.04 repositories?

Comment: My bad, I have 14.04... my home PC has 16.04 and I got confused. Updating question and tags.

Comment: After messing around with packages, I rebooted and now I cant login thought graphic mode... I can only login thought terminal....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)

Answer (score 0):

first you should install synaptic

> sudo apt-get install synaptic

and then install cups from synaptic (by checking cups in synaptic) it will take care of dependency.

Comment: After running the command, it outputs the same as if it were "wine" package, poiting out each dependency...

Comment: you have to install wine package through synaptic tool not using terminal

Answer (score 0):

This is the procedure to install any Wine version that you want without having to deal with external repositories, this is the MANUAL procedure.

Installing older/different versions of Wine than the latest ones from the repositories in Debian/Ubuntu system is a pain in the rear extremity.

Plan B: consider hopping over to Manjaro, if it's possible for you to do so. Why? Because the Manjaro version of the Wine package comes bundled IN A SINGLE PACKAGE, and you install it using A SINGLE COMMAND:

```
sudo pacman -U /local_path/wine-staging-5.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
or, in the case you miss dependencies..
sudo pacman -Sy /path/wine...
(I think that's the command... I'm not in Manjaro right now,
the Sy command will download the dependencies for you 
WITHOUT performing a full system upgrade, only the packages you need...
pacman -U is the equivalent of sudo dpkg -i , for manual install)
```

OK. If hopping over to Arch/Manjaro is NOT a possibility for you, these below are the steps for MANUALLY installing older versions of Wine on Debian/Ubuntu-based distros:

1. Let's say you want to install Wine version 4.1 (one of the last versions of Wine before the Wineprefix size increased from 100 MB straight to 600 MB, without no additional benefits and no avoidance of the usual bugs from the last 10 years...)
   Go to https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/
   and download all packages that have 4.1 in their name (they should have the same Date to them)

In the case of Wine 4.1 (the version that I've found to be the optimal one) these are the packages you need. You always will need FIVE packages in total.

```
winehq-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging_4.1_buster_i386.deb
wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging-i386_4.1_buster_i386.deb
```

2. Installation order. Here comes the tricky part, after you do it the 1st time it should be easier the next times. First, you install the biggest i386 package, always. Then, you install the small i386 package. Then, install the big amd64 package, and the small amd64 package. The last to be installed should be winehq (which only comes in amd64 form)

Below is a copy of my bash history with the order of commands I used to do this in shortest time.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-i386_4.1_buster_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging_4.1_buster_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/winehq-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
...
winecfg    <used to create the initial Wine prefix>
<use these ones below to reassure that you have all libs installed correctly>
...
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 WINEARCH=win32 winecfg  <to test if 32-bit is working OK>
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 WINEARCH=win64 winecfg  <to test if 64-bit is working OK>
<you should not see errors in the terminal of the type
"but the wrong architecture is being used" >
```

Notice how you need to run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

every single time each package is installed. That will guarantee that the individual dependencies to each package are installed and configured, before you install the next package. (this is only needed the 1st time you do this... after that, you can put all these dependencies, store them in a Backup location, and install them all-at-once using sudo dpkg -i /path/*.deb )

3. Sometimes, and I don't understand why this happens, you won't be able to use Wine 64 bits, or you won't be able to use Wine 32 bits, one of the two. If that happens, simply re-install one of the big Wine packages again (depending if you need amd64 or i386)

   sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb

It's very unfortunate that Wine has been distributed like this on Debian/Ubuntu system, it's an overcomplicated process with a lot of time wasted. The way Manjaro does it should become the official way Wine is distributed from now on.