# Unmet dependencies when trying to install r-base

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, r

I have a problem with installation of apps from the terminal.
These are examples of this problem:

```
ratanak@ratanak-walker:~$ sudo apt-get install httrack
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 httrack : Depends: libhttrack2 (>= 3.48.24) but it is not going to be installed
 rstudio : Depends: libjpeg62 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 but it is not installable
           Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 but it is not installable
           Recommends: r-base (>= 2.11.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

ratanak@ratanak-walker:~$ sudo apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.4.0-1xenial0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.4.0-1xenial0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
 rstudio : Depends: libjpeg62 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 but it is not installable
           Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I notice that these problem started when I started installing program r.

Comment: Have you tried: `sudo apt --fix-broken install` first?

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you running ?

Also make sure you system is fully updated before trying to install new packages.

(1) sudo apt-get update (2) sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: I'm running 17.04.

Answer (score 27):

This problem is solved.

```
sudo apt install --fix-broken
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Thank you!
Cheers!

Comment: This worked for me, thank you...but why? What does --fix-broken install actually do?

Comment: It works also for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: In my case, it was enough to use the first command `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Hi, Dowlers. I think when we have problem "unmet dependencies" we use: $ sudo apt --fix-broken install

Comment: @Dowlers See https://askubuntu.com/questions/263378/how-to-fix-dependencies-broken-packages/263390 for an explanation.

Comment: running ```sudo apt --fix-broken install``` cause any other issues ?

Answer (score 5):

run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

tell me if that helps, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sudo apt full-upgrade` -- that will remove some packages if necessary.